# Is there a way to maintain referential integrity/data consistency among models if I'm using the MongoDB connector?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

Let's say I have a `user` who possesses a `referencesMany` relationship with `home`. That would look something like this in `common/models/user.json`:

`"relations": {
    "homes": {
      "type": "referencesMany",
      "model": "home",
      "foreignKey": "homeIds"
    }
  },`

So, as I associate many `home` models with the `user` model, the array of `homeIds` grows larger:

```
{
    "homeIds": ["1", "2", "3"]
}
```

But, let's say I delete the `home` object with the id of "1".

How do I ensure that every other model referencing this model is updated to *remove* its reference to the deleted model?

Comment: usually this is called "cascade" delete; I am not sure loopback currently supports this. You could use a "beforeDelete" hook even if that's maybe a bit cumbersome

Comment: @faboolous, I'm guessing this would require that I modify `common/models/user.js`. I may give this a try, as it seems promising: https://github.com/rocknrolla777/loopback-cascade-delete-mixin

Comment: @faboolous, do you know of a good way to updates multiple collections at once in Loopback? I'm not even talking about `delete`--I mean `put`/`patch`.

Comment: it has been a while I have been working with loopback, but this seems related: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/2123

Comment: @faboolous, another one for you: how do I use the `common/models/model.js` file? Does using this file mean that I can't also use the model.json file?

Comment: it's complementary, some things you can define in the json file, some things - like code, like the hooks - you need to have in the js file